# overlap one image on the other image in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 images, I have to display one image on the other image.I need to display the 2 images like below exactly.
[image]

The following is the code which I have tried, its not coming prperly.can any one please help me to fis this issue?

```css
.my_banner{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4s7Z.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="my_banner"></img>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ8Ku.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: on your css "left" use calc to have dynamic position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `position: absoulute;` and adjust the top and left to fit it.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
}

.overlap {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 60%;
  top: 15%;
  left: 13%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ8Ku.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
<img class="overlap" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4s7Z.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: your solution working fine, but the tabs which worked fine previously. now the ssize of the tabs and text became very small. see this http://snag.gy/6Uma8.jpg

Comment: Would you post the tabs' html parts? Need to check the structure to adjust.

Comment: Strange, I put it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqj5m04r/) and it seems fine.

Comment: i am very sorry, it was my mistake , browser was in zoom out.

Comment: It's ok, glad it help you :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/8/

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4s7Z.gif' alt=""> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ8Ku.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: top center;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
}

.banner img {
    left: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 12%;
}
```